# How to get a QR bar code using Motorola tablet ET1 scanner in my android app?

Tags: android, qr-code, motorola, motorola-droid, motorola-emdk

I just started android development with device Motorola tablet ET1. This device has a barcode scanner. I want to make an simple app which scans the barcode using ET1 scanner and show me information. I do not want to use Zxing or any other project for that. If ET1 has a scanner then there should be some simple way to use it in any app. I googled it but could not find any help. Any idea how can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not related to your question, but since you have an ET1, would you know how to flash a custom ROM to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the [ET1 Enterprise Tablet Integrator Guide](http://support.symbol.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=14851103apdf&sliceId=&dialogID=535406286&stateId=1%200%20535394942) suggests you just need to:

1. Ensure that an application is open on the ET1 and a text field is in focus (text cursor in text field).
2. Aim the Scan Module exit window at a bar code.
3. Press and hold either Scan/Action button. The red laser aiming pattern turns on to assist in aiming. Ensure that the bar code is within the area formed by the aiming pattern. The Decode LED lights red to indicate that data capture is in process.

So, all you need is an EditText in your app, and to give it focus.

There are other alternative ways too - I suggest you have a look at the guide for more details.  There's lots of information about the ET1 on the Motorola website if you need further information.